# Real-world instantiation of NIZK protocol from Fiat-Shamir

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, fiat-shamir, non-interactiveness

So I understand how one can use Fiat-Shamir to turn a HVZK sigma protocol into a non-interactive zk protocol in the random oracle model. My problem though is I don't understand why is this useful.

If I wanted to use a NIZK in something and I choose a protocol based on Fiat-Shamir, this would mean I have to choose a hash function which surely invalidates the zk proof in the ROM. So do I know anything about the zk-ness of this instantiated protocol I'm then using?

Normally for proofs using the ROM I believe the idea is that even though you have to choose a real hash function, if you make a good choice your hash function simulates randomness close enough that it shouldn't *really* matter to the proof of security and therefore you have some justification/belief that what you're using remains secure. But for NIZK this doesn't appear to be the case and the proof of zk fully breaks down if you have to choose a hash function.

If this is the case then why do people bother with creating NIZK schemes via Fiat-Shamir which have only been proved in ROM?

Edit: To add more details of my issue with the ROM for NIZK protocols - when constructing a simulation of the transcript, the simulator has control of the output of the random oracle. This can never be achieved using a real (sufficiently good) hash-function so simulated transcripts cannot be shown to exist using a similar argument to the ROM proof. Therefore nothing about the ZK-ness of the protocol using a concrete has function is known.

Comment: There seems to be a misconception on proofs in the ROM. All proofs in the ROM are basically heuristic. They don't guarantee anything upon the choice of a concrete hash function. This is basically how to know, there could not exist a hash function that implements a random oracle. Now, for concrete hash, we can get certain confidence that it *behaves* like a random oracle. So, it doesn't matter whether it's HVZK or other scheme, proofs in the ROM do not really carry over  when we fix a concrete hash.

Comment: @MarcIlunga I mean that is exactly what I was saying but I don't agree with the sentence "Now, for concrete hash, we can get certain confidence that it behaves like a random oracle" for proofs of NIZK in the ROM. Precisely because to me it seems like the entire proof breaks down once you have to choose a hash function unlike other ROM proofs where a good enough hash function should behave similarly to a ROM. In a NIZK ROM proof you need more than just "a good enough hash function should behave similarly to a ROM" which I why I query the usefulness of such proofs entirely.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the proof breaks down? The point I am maling is that the proof always beaks down even for other ROM proofs. e.g.: There exists signatures schemes secure in the rom but insecure for any choice of hash function, even good enough ones. AFAIK, the situation is similar with Fiat Shamir. In the sense that, v theses counter examples are somewhat contrived but nevertheless valid counter Examples to the "soundness" of the ROM

Comment: What is quite concerning with the F-S at the moment is non interactive recursive proofs. Which seemgling runs directly into issues of trying to simulate a random oracle with finte resources.

Comment: @MarcIlunga You make a good point. Instead of answering your question I'd instead like to ask another one - since there exists these schemes which are secure in ROM but insecure for any choice of hash function, what is the purpose of a proof in ROM? I see many NIZK protocols which only give security proofs in the ROM - it seems to me that this adds no value as it adds no assurance to the security of the protocol since as you say there are counterexamples. So why do people bother with proofs in ROM at all?

Comment: I suppose you'd need a new question per the rules of the forum. But briefly, proofs in the ROM still extremely useful. They inform our understanding of security. For many "real-world" protocols proven in the ROM, no insecurity is known. In fact, there's been some work on formalizing this notion: "RO don't exist, but for some protocols a hash function might be fine". Similarly, there's also indifferentiability: if we idealize (say the keccack perm.), then the sponge behaves like a RO and proofs* in the ROM caries over. Caveat: we are still idealizing things, and it doesn't work for some proofs.

Comment: @MarcIlunga Fair enough that makes sense. I think I am returning to my understanding I had when I asked the question but it's been a long time so I had forgotten where I had got to :)
I think this would be my reply: if I accept that a proof in the ROM say for a signature scheme doesn't prove security but gives confidence that the scheme could be secure, it's not clear to me why that logic should also apply to NIZK schemes. The way I understand F-S in the ROM, this actually tells us nothing about the ZK of the protocol with a concrete hash function which is why I'm questioning it's relevance.

Comment: At this point, you'll have to give a more precise description of the qualitative difference you see between ROM proofs for NIZK vs other schemes. Otherwise, it's a little bit unclear what you are contesting. AFAIK, I don't see any difference. Also on signature scheme: it would be odd to have confidence in a ROM proof for Schnorr signature but not the F-S in general. Schnorr's signature is at its heart an F-S construction. So it would be helpful if you could better describe what seems to be the issue.

Comment: @MarcIlunga I've added some more details to the post. Unfortunately, as it has been a while it's difficult for me to add more. Essentially, I can see the justification that security proof in the ROM gives confidence for real security (but is not a real proof) but due to the simulator needing to control the output of the ROM I don't see why a ZK-proof in the ROM implies anything about the ZK-ness of a real instantiation of the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

> But for NIZK this doesn't appear to be the case and the proof of zk fully breaks down if you have to choose a hash function

Why you say so?

The original HVZKP's Simulator is a good starting point for Fiat-Shamir NIZK's Simulator since the hash output is uniform enough. The added requirement is that RO must be programmable by the Simulator (maintaining the uniformity), to take into account the fact that simulators often play with stuff out of order.
ROs (and hashes) commit their output to the input, so they aren't programmable, they enforce a temporal order of messages; but remember that Simulators don't play with the rule of the protocol, they can produce fake transcripts acting out of protocol rules, and Random Oracle/Hash programmability is one of their "superpowers"

So, IMHO, passing from theoretic RO to actual Hash the only additional assumption for ZK is just enough uniformity of hash output.

### EDIT TO ANSWER OP's FOLLOW-UP COMMENT

Fiat-Shamir prescribes the Random Oracle used by the prover and by the verifier is the *same*.
Simulator is an entity playing out of protocol rules, but verifier has to follow them. So in Fiat-Shamir when the simulator is progamming the random oracle, it programs it for both the prover and verifier. Imagining the verifier using "original" oracle instead of the simulator-programmed-one puts him out of protocol, so it's out of our boundaries.

Using Hashes to simulate RO means prover and verifier have their own implementations of the prescribed hash, but it doesn't mean they can use different ones (if they want to follow the protocol); the simulator has to programme both the prover's and verifier's hash implementations.

Of course this sounds very strange, but not so much if you take into account that sometimes rewinding capability of simulator in interactive proofs is represented as prover and verifier being VMs in a computer and the simulator being the VMs hypervisor, able to pause and repeat their runs manipulating their state: in that case simulator can pause and rewind time flow... a quite huge superpower I would say :)

Coming back to our verifier calling an hash... now the prover and the verifier are VM which never interact (a part from the prover leaving the proof somewhere for the verifier to read it), but they both call their functions implementing the hash. And now our "hypervisor" simulator can change how both those functions works... why this should be worst than pausing and rewinding time?

Your central point seems to be the fact a verifier using "original" hash (the one not programmed by the simulator) would recognize the simulator's fake transcript:

- I have just said in that case the verifier wouldn't be following protocol rules cause it would use a RO/hash different from the one of entity pretending to be the prover;
- more, that detection capability imho is fundamental in any non-interactives proofs (Fiat-Shamir based or not): otherwise NI-ZKPs would be deniable, making themselves useless (a NI prover could always pretend that a previously published proof is fake and produced by a simulator)

Comment: Well a Simulator should simulate a real proof right? But if it chooses the hash function then with overwhelming probability it won't be the one chosen at the start of the protocol. And so it can't simulate a proof because it would be immediately obvious that it's using a different hash function to the one used in the protocol. Because from the transcript of the proof you can easily check if H(t,y) =/= H'(t,y) where H is the hash function I chose and H' is the hash function chosen by the Simulator.

Comment: You are saying something very specific there by assuming that the hash function is chosen by the protocol. It could be baked into the protocol in which case the simulator does not need to choose anything.

Comment: @Proliferate309 I have just edited my answer to get the space to answer your comment

Comment: @Lev was your comment for me or for the Proliferate309 ? If It was for my initial answer, please let me know if my follow-up still miss your point!

Comment: Thanks for the update but it feels like you might be misunderstanding my question a bit. 
I get in the ROM the simulator can prescribe hash function for all parties. But I am talking about a real instantiation of a zk protocol and given ROM proof does tell us anything about the zk-ness of this instantiation? 
i.e. we know the protocol is zk under ROM but do we know anything about the zk-ness of the real protocol? My intuition/guess would be to try use ROM proof but adapt to real world. But how could we show a Simulator exists for the real-wrld version of the protocol (and therefore show zk)?

Comment: and if the ROM proof can't be adapted to this real-world instantiation then what's the point in having the ROM proof - what value does it add?

Comment: What I'm not getting in your POV is why you accept that an uniform/random enough hash is ok for security/soundness of "normal" proof, but you think it's not enough for ZKness... I mean if it's ok for the former imho it should be ok for the latter too, if I'm correct about the fact that the perfect randomness is what a real hash miss in comparison with an ideal RO (of course taking for granted you are ok for ZKness in ROM)

Comment: I can understand your concern @Proliferate309. I think programmable random oracles are very peculiar and non-intuitive.

Comment: @baro77 Because for a 'normal' proof the only property of the ROM you need is the true randomnes. So if you replace the ROM with a real hash function that is prety close to random the ROM proof gives a good justification that the real hash function is also secure (although it doesn't actually say anything about the real hash function). But for a zk proof via Fiat-Shamir this isn't enough - you also need the fact that the Simulator can ensure the challenge is the hash of the commitment. It does this by choosing the output of the ROM - this is something which simply cannot be made to (continued)

Comment: happen with a real hash function, hence why imo the proof of the zk-ness for ROM says absolutely nothing about the zk-ness of the protocol when you try to implement it in real-life, and which is why I'm questioning the purpose of such a proof.

Comment: thanks, now I get that your concern is about programmability and not about randomness. I know it's an open problem (e.g. Matthew Green is tweeting about it during last days - BTW are you the one he was asked by?); imho one side to explore is that Simulators seem not necessarily required to exist in real world, they are just required to exist out of protocol rules; more, I want to stress that any NI-ZK proof with "real world" simulator would be deniable (and so useless): from that POV the fact that Simulator doesn't exist "in real world" seems a feature.